# Constants and simplifying enum value access

Tags: java, enums

For an `enum` with only one member variable, is there a simpler (and best practices) way to access it without the use of an accessor method? I had alternatively considered using `public static final` variables in a constants class but the more I read, the more people suggest using `enum` as the way to encapsulate those values.

To attempt to illustrate what I mean, I've included the following example:

```
public enum FILE_NAME {

   MAIN("MAIN.TXT"),
   ATTACHMENT("ATTACHMENT.TXT"),
   OTHER("OTHER.HTM");

   private String fileName;

   FILE(String fileName) {
     this.fileName = fileName;
   }

   public String getfileName() {
     return fileName;
   }
}
```

I would then normally access that value like so:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(bos);

// Add file
zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(FILE_NAME.MAIN.getFileName()));
```

For my particular use case, I'd much prefer to be access the filename with a call like:

```
...
zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(FILE_NAME.MAIN));
```

In doing so, the code reduces the length (and almost syntactic redundancy of calling a filename of a file) of the call needed to access the `MAIN` file name text. While this may not even be feasible or desirable, I'm curious to know if it's worth considering.

Thanks.

Comment: The suggested `toString` override answer seems to have disappeared. That does solve my problem and give me the functionality I am after. This works for me because `toString` is called by default it would seem.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't solve my problem. I still need to call `toString` in the `ZipEntry` example above. It only worked in my testing with `System.out.println()`. So with that in mind, looks like I have no alternative but to use `FILE.MAIN.getFileName()` or some such accessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify it, and still keep it *safe*, use a `public final String` field for the file name:

```
public enum FileType {
    MAIN("MAIN.TXT"),
    ATTACHMENT("ATTACHMENT.TXT"),
    OTHER("OTHER.HTM");

    // Name in all-caps to make it look like the constant it is
    public final String FILENAME;

    private FileType(String fileName) {
       this.FILENAME = fileName;
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(FileType.MAIN.FILENAME));
```

Note that change of class name to "FileType" to better adhere to java standards.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian. So does this give me any benefits over simply having a constants class with a bunch of `public static final String`s?

Comment: @speedRS Absolutely yes! Using an enum makes the filename value *strongly typed*. If you put this usage behind a facade that accepts the filename you cna make its parameter FileType - thus storngly typing the call. If you use String constants instead (sometimes called *stringly typed*) and have your facade method use a String parameter, there is no way to ensure that programmers *use* these constants - eg they can pass in `MyConstants.MAIN_FILE_NAME` or pass in "fred" - the compiler can't check anything if the parameter type is String.

Comment: That clarifies things for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the following would work better

```
public enum FILE_NAME {

   MAIN("MAIN.TXT"),
   ATTACHMENT("ATTACHMENT.TXT"),
   OTHER("MAIN.TXT");

   private String fileName;

   FILE(String fileName) {
     this.fileName = fileName;
   }

   public void putEntry ( ZipOUtputStream zip )
   {
         zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(this.getFileName()));
   }

   public String getfileName() {
     return fileName;
   }
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
FILE_NAME.MAIN.putEntry(zip);
```

Comment: I should clarify, that the file name is also used in other places such as reading writing details in XML. For example - <URI>MAIN.TXT</URI>. So the usage can vary.

Comment: Yeah, I often do this kind of enum inversion-of-control.  In this case, if there are other things that are special for each file, speedRS (the OP) might want to consider using a FILE enum, as opposed to a FILE_NAME enum, and put all the file-specific polymorphism in there.  You can do the same thing with normal class polymorphism, of course, but if everything is small it's a lot more concise to use enums.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will take them onboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can have aliases

```
enum Pet
{ 
    cat("meow"), 
    dog("woof") 

    String getSound()
}


public static final Pet CAT = Pet.cat;

public static final String MEOW = Pet.cat.getSound();
```